# Конвертор кода на python в код на C или C++

Tags: python, c

Не подскажете такой под линукс? И ссылочку бы..

Comment: можно глянуть boost::python

Comment: А разве это возможно?

Comment: Возможно. Преобразование же Pascal, Fortran, Ada->c возможно же? А C->asm? Вопрос в том, нужно ли это.

Comment: Преобразование из Pascal, Fortran и Ada не так уж не сложно. Всё-таки языки похожие. Как преобразовать eval в Python?

Comment: eval - это функция. преобразовывать её реализацию? Даже если она на python написана, а не является C-модулем, в чём её особенная сложность?

Comment: Не всегда можно надёжно преобразовать скрипт в статичный код. Будет масса проблем и надёжного решения никогда не получите, а проблем огребёте.. да ещё и скорость может не вырасти (как это с perl, например).

Comment: Не нужен статичный код. Функция eval возвратит ссылку на Python Object - объект структуры в C или класса в C++.

Answer (score 4):

- [Cython](http://cython.org/) - это язык, основанный на Python, который компилируется в C/C++; чтобы получить компилируемый из Python код, нужна дополнительная работа.
- [Shed Skin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) - это экспериментальный компилятор, который компилирует код на Python (с некоторыми ограничениями) в С++.

Comment: добавлю http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/, на котором основан Cython